# WatchDeadLock Class in .Net

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, parallel-processing, deadlock

Any one knows in which assembly and namespace the 'WatchDeadLock' class falls under.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the `WatchDeadLock` class from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Parallel_Programming/NET4ParallelIntro.aspx). The class is part of the downloadable code from that article (click Download Source Code at the top of the article). It is not a class that is part of the .NET Framework. The class is in a file called `WatchDeadlock.cs`.